# any one who can help me with an online bookshelf?

Tags: javascript, server, quickbooks-online

Is anyone there who can help me to find a server which can store E-Contents (E-Book, video and podcast) and provide an embedding option to be used in my website?

Comment: Beware this is not a stackoverflow question. AWS can do that if you are okay paying for it. or else https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/30/amazon-ec2-alternatives/

Answer (score 0):

You can use The Preview Wizard for books.

> The Preview Wizard is designed to let you quickly, easily, and
>   reliably integrate previews with your site. You can embed a book
>   viewer, link to Book Search, or even add a preview "popup" window to
>   your site—all you need to do is generate the code and paste it onto
>   your page. You can also customize this code using some simple
>   JavaScript functions.

[Instructions](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/preview-wizard#generateCode)

[Demo](https://google-developers.appspot.com/books/examples/previewwizard-embed)